# How to NOT initiate ComponentDidMount() method in React 17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

I have a component A that gets mounted when the user visits my HomePage.
In its ComponentDidMount() method, I fetch data from a database that gets display on screen.

```
class A extends React.Component{
...
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
    ///set States
    }, function() {axios.get(
    // get params
    )})
}
...
}
```

Then I click a link which redirects me to another page of Compnent B whilst sending my state in props, so the state from Component A does not get lost.
When I return to my home page of component A, componentDidMount fetches these data again.
Though this is not a mistake, it does create an additional database request which hinders performance.
How can I call componentDidMount() conditionally?

Comment: You can't, React controls the component lifecycle. What you ***can*** do though is conditionally invoke your data fetching. For this though you'll likely need some global state (React context/redux/etc) to track that the DB request has been made and to not do it again (presumably for *some* duration).

Comment: A better solution would be to store the fetched data in a shared parent of `A` and `B`, but a hacky workaround would be to send the state back to `A` when navigating from `B`.  A => B => A it's honestly silly but it should work.  Your `componentDidMount` would check if `this.props.data` is set, and only do the fetch if it is `undefined`.

Comment: Thats what I did but seems like an amateur solution and ugly

Comment: I agree that it is not a great solution.  Ideally you want to move the `state` higher up in the tree.  You can either pass it down via props through a shared parent like `App` or use something like redux which uses a context `Provider` to make the state available to all its descendants.